# Notation involving the symmetric group $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, symmetric-groups, operads

I'm reading [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0003052.pdf) paper by Hinich and he uses two notations involving the symmetric group $S_n$ that he doesn't clarify, so I assume that they are standard, but I don't know what they mean.

The first of them appears at the end of page 3:

> Let $\mathscr{O}$ be an operad in a tensor category $\mathscr{A}$. Let $V$ be an $\mathbb{S}$-object in $\mathscr{A}$. The free $\mathscr{O}$-algebra generated by $V$ is defined to be
>   $$
> \Bbb{F}_{\mathscr{O}}(V)=\bigoplus_{n\geq 0}\mathscr{O}(n)\otimes_{S_n}V^{\otimes n}
> $$
>   with a canonical $\mathscr{O}$-algebra structure.

I think it doesn't make sense to take tensor product with respect to $S_n$ (as in $R$-modules with respect to $R$) so I guess it has to do with the $S_n$-equivariance of the action of the operad $\mathscr{O}$ on the algebra, but I'm not sure.

Then there is a dual definition

> If $V$ is an $\mathbb{S}$-object in $\mathscr{A}$, the cofree coalgebra cogenerated by $V$ is defined to be
>   $$
> \Bbb{F}^*_{\mathscr{C}}(V)=\bigoplus_{n\geq 0}\left(\mathscr{C}(n)\otimes V^{\otimes n}\right)^{S_n}
> $$

In this case I have no clue what it means. It cannot be the maps to $S_n$ since for $n=1$ it is used a few pages later (after equation (9)) that it is just $V$. Maybe it is just a direct sum of $n!$ copies, but that's just a guess.

I hope someone recognizes these notations. Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the tensor product is over the group ring $R S_n$, while the superscript $S_n$ means "$S_n$-invariants" (aka $S_n$-fixed space).

Comment: Possibly the $\left( \cdot \right)^{S_n}$ means maps *from* $S_n$ to that set. In general, $A^B$ (for sets) denotes maps from $B$ to $A$, not the other way around.

Comment: @JohnHughes True, I was confused, that would be consistent with the case $n=1$

Comment: @darijgrinberg does the tensor product over the group ring $RS_n$ make sense in any tensor (symmetric monoidal) category? And could you explain what you mean by $S_n$-fixed space?

Comment: Oh, that I don't know (particularly since there are several non-equivalent definitions of tensor category floating around). The $S_n$-fixed space $V^{S_n}$ of an $RS_n$-module $V$ is the $R$-submodule $\left\{v \in V \mid \sigma v = v \text{ for all } \sigma \in S_n\right\}$; once again, I don't know how to define this in an arbitrary tensor category. Are we at least over a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra? In this case, the $S_n$-fixed space is the image of the idempotent $\dfrac{1}{n!} \sum\limits_{\sigma \in S_n} \sigma \in \operatorname{End}V$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg the operad for which I need those constructions is an operad of $\Bbb{Q}$-algebras so I can assume that. Thanks for you comment. I guess an action of $S_n$ is assumed on $V$ too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked it up in [*Algebraic Operads*](http://irma.math.unistra.fr/~loday/PAPERS/LodayVallette.pdf) by Loday and Vallette (chapter 5).

The first one is the tensor product taken under the action of $S_n$. On $\mathscr{O}(n)$ it is the action that has by definition of $\Bbb{S}$-object and in $V^{\otimes n}$ is a rearrangement of the coordinates.

The second one is the space of invariant elements under this action.